# How to get the DisplayNameAttribute when it is in another class

Tags: c#, system.componentmodel

I am having a problem with the following code:

```
//This class can't be changed for is part of an EF data context.
public partial class person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//I have this partial just to access the person DisplayNameAttribute 
[MetadataType(typeof(person_metaData))]
public partial class person
{
}

//And this is the MetaData where i am placing the 
public class person_metaData
{
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How do i get the DisplayNameAttribute when it is in another class? Thank's in advance!

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by in another class?

Comment: Attributes are applied to the *type*, not to an *instance of that type*. Therefore, every instance of your entity will have the exact same metadata. I think the solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve is incorrect. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Steve, I am getting data from Entity Framework and writing it to Excell file. Thus, i need the properties of an Entity and write it as the column header. But, the property cod_person i would like to put as Cod. Person. Am I clear? Thank's for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider` for your class has been registered correctly, the `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor` class will honour the attributes from your metadata class.

Add this somewhere near the start of your program:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(
    new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(person)), 
    typeof(person));
```

Then access the properties:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(person));
PropertyDescriptor prop = properties["Name"];
string displayName = prop.DisplayName;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider` class directly:

```
var provider = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(person));
ICustomTypeDescriptor typeDescriptor = provider.GetTypeDescriptor(typeof(person), null);
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = typeDescriptor.GetProperties();
PropertyDescriptor prop = properties["Name"];
string displayName = prop.DisplayName;
```

**NB:** Your `DisplayName` attribute doesn't currently change the display name, so you won't see any difference. Change the value passed to the attribute constructor to see that the type descriptor is working.

Comment: Thanks Richard, i am having a try!

Comment: It worked Richard! Very straightforward solution and you got to the point so well. Many, many and many thanks!